# Is it possible to "expand" a logic so that its set of tautologies is more informative?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Creating a new logic $L'$ by adding connectives to $L$.

It's possible to distinguish propositional logics with the same set of tautologies but different consequence relations. For example, [the three-valued logic LP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraconsistent_logic#Comparison_with_classical_logic) has the same tautologies as classical logic but a different consequence relation.

A set of tautologies is a nice mathematical object to work with, though.

I'm wondering if there are ways of taking an existing logic and *expanding it with new connectives* so that it is *completely described in some sense* by its tautologies.

---

I can think of one way to do it, but I'm not sure that it works. It's sort of a stab in the dark. The key idea is that I want to add connectives that *behave like* conjunction and negation in classical logic in certain contexts. The idea is to build *up* by adding new connectives, rather than building "down" from classical logic by adding a modal operator like $\square$ that sandboxes expressions in $L$.

In particular, let $L$ be a logic that does not contain the connectives $\circ$ (a conjunction-like operation I'm going to call *strong conjunction*) and $\sim$ (*strong negation*).

Let $L'$ be a logic that does have $\circ$ and $\sim$, in addition to all the connectives of $L$, and no additional connectives.

Also, let $L'$ satisfy the following rule:

$$ \Gamma \; (\vdash_L) \; \varphi \;\; \text{if and only if} \;\; (\vdash_{L'}) \; ({\sim}(\Gamma_1 \circ \Gamma_2 \circ \cdots \circ\Gamma_n \circ {\sim}\varphi)) $$

In lieu of new axioms and inference rules for $\circ$ and ${\sim}$, I define a notion of *equivalent* well-formed formulas and insist that equivalent well-formed formulas are both tautologies at exactly the same time.

In addition, $a \circ b$ is equivalent to $b \circ a$, $a \circ (b \circ c)$ is equivalent to $(a \circ b) \circ c$ and $a$ is equivalent to ${\sim}{\sim}a$.

$$ \text{If $\varphi$ is equivalent to $\varphi'$, then $\varphi$ is a tautology if and only if $\varphi'$ is a tautology} $$

I'm not sure that this construction works though because I don't know how to nail down what should happen when a new connective appears *under* an old one, such as:

$$ (a \circ \lnot b) \to c \;\; \text{has two new connectives appearing under $\to$, which existed previously.} $$